# First timer PHP edit to update html, some errors

Tags: php, html

this is my first time using PHP in a real project environment. The project is pretty simple, take an existing, working PHP site and update the HTML to be consistent with HTML5. After designing the HTML, I am inserting the PHP from the previous site. This works most of the time, but I get a few errors. For instance:

```
<?
$sec = $_GET['sec'];
if ($sec == "1") {
    echo ('Success!');
}
?>
```

Is causing the error:
Notice: `Undefined index: sec in /file_that_holds_site_build.`

Of course that is only if the url doesn't include the append tag (=1) that alerts the message.

So the question is this, what am I missing that causes the `$GET` when there is no `$sec`? How do I eliminate this error on first page load?

Comment: Just use `isset($_GET['sec'])` in a if-statement to see if it exists before you fetch the value

Answer (score 1):

You're getting that notice because you're trying to access an array index that doesn't exist in some scenarios. Here's how you should be getting the data out of the request.

```
$sec = array_key_exists('sec', $_GET) ? $_GET['sec'] : null;
```

Comment: As of PHP7 you can use the null coalescing operator for this as described in http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php
`$sec = $_GET['sec'] ?? null;`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone who provided possible answers to this question. It was Daniel that came up with the easiest fix. Again, I am just adjusting someone else's code to work, so a universal solve would involve too much of my own writing. To the point, the final code looks like this:

```
<?
if (isset($_GET["sec"])){
$sec = $_GET['sec'];
if ($sec == "1") {
echo ('Success! Your username and password have been sent via email.');
}}
?>
```

Notice the added if statement. As I said in a comment to Daniel, SO SIMPLE!

Thanks again for everyone's help. I hope to be likewise of service to you all soon.

Answer (score 0):

Simple just use `isset($_GET['sec'])` to check for the parameter `'sec'` before using it in the php code. That should eliminate the error. This is quite trivial I suppose.

Comment: That totally worked! Thank you for the response. I'll post the completed code in my own answer. Thanks again. SO SIMPLE!

Answer (score -1):

I often simply `extract()` the wohle `$_GET` super global and then either get the desired variable or not. As a kind of "declaration" I initialize each expected variable first with `false`. This way I find it much easier to handle than individually doing a check like `if(isset($_GET['element'])) ...`

```
$var1=$var2=$var3=false; // my desired variables
extract($_GET);          // everything I get from the form 
// or: extract($_REQUEST);

if ($var1) { /* do something with it */ }
```

Possible security risk:

Of course you should be aware that everybody could simply include their own variable as an argument to he page ...

Comment: This is not what you should ever do. This enables users to arbitrarily overwrite existing variables. For a given url of `?db=asdf`, and the code `$db = new mysqli(...); extract($_GET); echo $db;` will output `asdf`.

Comment: @castis: Point taken! Yes, *I did mention* the possibble side effects. For this reason I `extract($_GET)` *only once, at the very top* of my script. That way, nothing will be overwritten apart from the "initialisations" I mentioned before. But, sure, you need to know what you are doing!